# not refreshing data in angular js

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I write a web in mvc framework with angular js.

my application is:

```
var app = angular.module("AngularApp", []);
```

and my controller is:

```
app.controller("EmpCtrl", function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
GetAllEmployee();
function GetAllEmployee() {

    var getAllEmployee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
    getAllEmployee.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees = emp.data;

    }, function () {
        alert('data not found');
    });
}


$scope.deleteEmployee = function (id) {
    var getData = EmployeeService.DeleteEmp(id);
    getData.then(function (msg) {
        GetAllEmployee();
        alert('Employee Deleted...');
        $scope.h1message = true;
        $scope.message = "ED";
    }, function () {
        $scope.h1message = true;
        $scope.message = "Error in Deleting Record";
    });
}
});
```

and my service is:

```
app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http) {
this.getEmployee = function () {
    debugger;
    return $http.get("/EmployeeModels/GetAllEmployee");
};

//Delete Employee
this.DeleteEmp = function (employeeId) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/EmployeeModels/deleteEmployee",
        params: {
            employeeId: JSON.stringify(employeeId)
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

});

and my mvc action is :

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public JsonResult GetAllEmployee()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var employeeList = db.EmployeeModels.ToList();
            return Json(employeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    //DeleteEmployee
    public string DeleteEmployee(string employeeId)
    {
        if (employeeId != null)
        {
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(employeeId);
            var employeeList = db.EmployeeModels.Find(no);
            db.EmployeeModels.Remove(employeeList);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Employee Deleted";
        }
        else { return "Invalid Employee"; }
    }
```

and html file is:

```
<div ng-app="AngularApp" ng-init="name='hn';backGroundColor='red';
 person={firstname:'jo',lastname:'hary'}">
<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('emp.EmployeeId')">employee id</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('Address')">addres</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('EmailId')">email id</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('EmployeeName')">employee name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees|orderBy:orderByMe">
            <td> {{emp.EmployeeId}}</td>
            <td> {{emp.Address}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.EmailId}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.EmployeeName}}</td>
            <td><a data-ng-click="deleteEmployee(emp.EmployeeId)" style="cursor:pointer;">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

the view of data is ok. but when I add record to table of database, view not refresh data?

Comment: you need to call the api to update with the latest data

Comment: How and where call api?

Comment: on your button click

Comment: what is instruction?

Comment: I add delete action to above code. and I add "GetAllEmployee();" to delete method. But  when I delete one record, view not update. please check code again.

Comment: do you have teamviewer? so that i can check

Comment: please check your mail: saj....aran@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

Your view not refresh data because, your method GetAllEmployee() is called once, at the loading of page. you need to refresh your page.

Comment: ok when I refresh the page, data is update, but I want when a record is delete, view is update. I add GetAllEmployee() in delete function, but not refreshing data.

Comment: In your delete function, you can delete emp deleted in employees or call again your dataBase to get the new lists of employees